# Powershell - Test-Path always return false even the file exists

Tags: powershell

In the following code, Test-Path always return false even though the file does exist.  I thought it was the special character in the variable but I use the curly braces to handle that.  Still it doesn't work.  Can someone help??  Thank you very much!!!

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $OriginalRootDir -Recurse -File).FullName |
ForEach-Object {
    ${In} = "'" + $_ + "'"
    ${Out} = ${In} -replace "Original", "Converted"

    if (-not (Test-Path -Path ${Out} -PathType Leaf))
    {
        #It always get in here even though the $Out does exist
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `"'" + $_ + "'"`? That looks really weird, this would evaluate to the equivalent of ```"'$_'"``` which then would probably end up testing the path `'$_'` instead of `$_` which is what you want. Just do `${In} = $_`

Comment: Thank you! I did the "'" + $_ + "'" because I needed to output that and form a commandline command, like "handbrakecli.exe -o " + ${Out}, but I could just do "handbrakecli.exe -o '" + ${Out} + "'" instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $OriginalRootDir -Recurse -File).FullName |
ForEach-Object {
    ${In}=$_
    ${Out} = ${In} -replace "Original", "Converted"

    if (-not (Test-Path -Path ${Out} -PathType Leaf))
    {
      echo 'not found'
    } else {
      echo 'found'
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting just code as an answer is not recommended. Please add an explanation